# a function called for each element from a hook problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that calls a function that inserts a component for each object from a hook and that hook is populated from an API all is working fine but the problem is this map is triggered whenever I change smth on the page also if I type a text on input and I don't want this to happen I want it only when I have my values from my DB.

```
  const test = () => {
            dbServices.map(serv => {
        serv.action = action(serv._id)
    })
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    getServices()
  }, [])
  
  test()
```

and here is my action

```
  const action = (id) => {
    console.log("test")
    return (
      <>
        <a onClick={() => { newpop(id) }} className="mr-3 text-primary">
          <i className="mdi mdi-pencil font-size-18 mr-3" id="edittooltip" />
          <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="edittooltip">
            Edit
          </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </a>
        <a onClick={() => delService(id)} className="text-danger">
          <i className="mdi mdi-close font-size-18 mr-3" id="deletetooltip" />
          <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="deletetooltip">
            Delete
          </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </a>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: This is because from what I can see your test function is called inside the render method. So this will be called on every change. If you only want this to happen once as well. Then move this code to the useEffect as well (Or create another useEffect to trigger a change for a certain prop)

Comment: if I move it to the useeffect will don't show my buttons maybe because the values are taken from an API and this takes time

Comment: It can only display the button when you have the server data right? Because you pass in server data to the action. If you want to display a button even without server data, then what should this button do ?

Comment: yeah i want to display buttons for the server data

Comment: and i get the server data with getServices

Comment: Do you keep track of your server data in a state? If you have the data in your state then you can render the state data. So when the state is an empty array you see nothing and when the state gets populated with the useEffect, then it will automatically render the actions. All you will have to save in the state are the ids as well because that is all you are using from the server

Comment: yes i do i keep my data on  const [dbServices, setDbServices] = useState([])

Comment: so can you help me with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling test have your main render function include the jsx code like this:

```js
  return(
    dbServices.map(({id}) => 
      <>
        <a onClick={() => { newpop(id) }} className="mr-3 text-primary">
          <i className="mdi mdi-pencil font-size-18 mr-3" id="edittooltip" />
          <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="edittooltip">
            Edit
          </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </a>
        <a onClick={() => delService(id)} className="text-danger">
          <i className="mdi mdi-close font-size-18 mr-3" id="deletetooltip" />
          <UncontrolledTooltip placement="top" target="deletetooltip">
            Delete
          </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </a>
      </>
    )
  )
```

Then when your state gets updated your render will automatically update as well.

Comment: i cant do this because i am working with a table from reactstrap

Comment: what you want to see

Comment: Your return where you render the table. The snipped I posted was when you only rendered the buttons. If you render a table you would probably add it at a column / header

Comment: no i dont for tabel i have this ``` <BootstrapTable                        responsive
                          keyField='_id'
                          data={dbServices}
                          columns={columns}
                          bordered={false}
                          striped={false}
                          classes={
                            "table table-centered table-nowrap"
                          }
                          headerWrapperClasses={"thead-light"}
                          pagination={paginationFactory(options)}

                        />```

Comment: maybe all i have to do is to move test() in a useEffect that will call only when the hook that store from my db is changed but idk to do this

Comment: I don't know what table you are using but the table should re-render when the data changes right? Can't you set the map initially where you call the setDbServices ? So setDbServices(call map here)